# apache SSL configuration using trusted certificates

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificate

It's my first time I'm dealing with SSL, I'd like to know, if I got this right or not.
**I create selfsigned Client-Certificates with a self created CA *my-own-CA.crt*.**

When I buy a Server-Certificate of a trusted CA, I get a
**SSL-Certificate-File *telesec-server.crt*

SSL-Certificate-Chain-File *telesec-ca.crt***
and I already got my
**SSL-Certificate-Key-File *my-server.key***

Now lets get to my apache2-configuration:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile /somepath/telesec-server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /somepath/my-server.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /somepath/telesec-ca.crt

# THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART FOR ME NOW
SSLCACertificatePath /somepath
SSLCACertificateFile /somepath/my-own-ca.crt

SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 10

<Location />
    SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL} in {"1234567890"}
</Location>
```

**Will this configuration allow me to use my self-signed client-certificate to get acces to my website, using a trusted server-certificate?**

Right now I'm having the server-certificate self signed. People accessing my website using those client-certificates getting some security messages. **Will this message be gone when I use the trusted server-certificate?**

**Will I be able to still use my self signed client-certificates?** My expectation here is also, that the users getting shown a safe server, but they can use the certificates I create on my own. This would mean, that the apache configuration options:
**SSLCACertificatePath** and **SSLCACertificateFile** are **optional field**, which check (if set), **if the client-certificate which is trying to connect is signed by the certificate set on this option**, right?

I just need to make this sure, because I'm going to buy a few server-certificates very soon, and I really want to have this questions answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will this configuration allow me to use my self-signed client-certificate to get acces to my website, using a trusted server-certificate?

Yes. (Although your certificate isn't *entirely* self-signed; it was signed by a CA, even if it's a custom CA. Maybe a better term would be "locally issued" or "custom issued"?)

Note that you only need one of "CACertificatePath" and "CACertificateFile", preferably the latter.

> Right now I'm having the server-certificate self signed. People accessing my website using those client-certificates getting some security messages. Will this message be gone when I use the trusted server-certificate?

Yes, that's exactly what the security message is about.

Comment: Yeah, correct spelling is still hard for me. Sorry for that. I looked again in the apache documentation to check the options CACertificatePath and CACertificateFile -  This can be used alternatively and/or additionally to SSLCACertificatePath. - you're right. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Mike: More specifically, OpenSSL can use either a bundled file or a "hashed directory", while GnuTLS only supports a single-file bundle. /// Speaking of which, note that `SSLCertificateChainFile` is deprecated as well – the "chain" contents should be appended to your certificate file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are discussing configuration, this could cause trouble:

```
 SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
```

Its a junk from the 1990s or 2000s. It will cause the dreaded [Obsolete Cryptography warning](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85532/chrome-showing-cryptography-as-obsolete) in Chrome.

Instead, try the following. You won't notice a difference, user agents like Chrome won't complain, and tools like SSL configuration checkers won't complain:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4
```

Personally, I use `SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2`, but we don't have anything but low value data on our site.

Finally, you can see the cipher suites that could be used with the `SSLCipherSuite` directive using OpenSSL from the command line:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!RC4:!MD5'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
```

If you have an RSA key at the server, then other authentication methods won't apply, like DSS. And you can probably remove PSK and SRP, too. So you could do something like:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!RC4:!MD5:!DSS:!PSK:!SRP'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll take a closer look on the security points here again later ... for now I'm doing some more tests, and I'll work on this specific problem again in a few days.